# Ajax in firefox - can't find solution on the net

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, post

this is my js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#f1").on('submit',(function(e) {
 
  var ActionType = getParameterByName('t');
  var projId = getParameterByName('pj');
  var QsId = getParameterByName('s');
  
  var urlString = "uploader.php?t=";
  urlString +=ActionType;
  urlString +="&pj=";
  urlString +=projId;
  urlString +="&s=";
  urlString +=QsId;
  
  
        //e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: urlString, 
            type: "POST",             
            data: new FormData(this), 
            contentType: false,       
            cache: false,             
            processData:false,        
            success: function(data)   
            {
                 //alert(callback); //Need to be changed
            }
        });
    }));
});
 //This function gets the parameter in the URL (GET) by name
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Firebug:
[image: Error Firebug]

Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  1198
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------266932244324698
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

I really can't understand the problem. Everything works perfect in Chrome and IE but not in FF

**EDIT**:
[image: Edit]

XHR RESPONE:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>UPLOAD</title>
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script language="javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="General.js"></script>
</head>
```

The rest is the html code for the table and etc..
It is the respone Header

Cache-Control   private
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  1151
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Thu, 26 Feb 2015 21:38:16 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk  PleskWin

Comment: Why do you have `(` and `)`  around your function?

Comment: So what is the error from the server? Why are you using post but sending the variables as a get in the url?

Comment: Can you post the debug stack instead of just the URL in red. Also, paste your XHR response.

Comment: @epascarello I am using those scopes for more clear view, it for my self. I am using Post and Get, It is how i process my data in upload.php, some of the data need to come in POST and other in GET. The debug and the stack fields are empty, but i posted what i found.

Comment: @EasyCo I add what i could find, if you can also say how to find the information, i will find it better and faster. I am not very familiar with FireBug :-(

Comment: @user3478552 open the developer tools in Firefox (`Tools->Web Developer->Toggle Tools`). Click on the `Network` tab at the top of the pane and click on `XHR` at the bottom of the pane. You'll then be able to click on the failing POST request and inspect the response by click on the `Response` tab.

Comment: There is nothing in the net tab that describes this request. But i think i found the problem: Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent. The problem is that I Do have the method set for post. Enctype i don't have because i process the data also in asp from the form. and asp can't get multipart/form-data.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to avoid the browser checking the enctype? Because the other browsers don't do it, and everything works smooth

Answer (score 0):

You have the form submitting and you are also have the race condition of the Ajax request. You need to cancel the form submission.

```
$("#f1").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```